# Send virtual joystick output using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, web2py

So I have implanted virtual joystick to my web2py application. I'm pulling x,y coordinates of the joystick and want to send them using ajax.

```js
$("#kk").change(function(){

    $.ajax({
      url: "{{=URL('default' , 'posalji')}}", 
      type: 'POST',
      data: {
        "ip": $("#ip").val(),
        "m1":$("#x").text(),
        "m2":$("#y").text(), 
        "dir":$("#y").text()
      },
      dataType: 'json',
    });
});
```

URL row works properly it is just web2py syntax.
My problem is with this change function. I made that my joystick changes the value of an input field. When that input filed is change, it doesn't activate function because (at least I think this is the reason) my input boxes doesn't get out of "focus".

Any help would be appreciated. 
I don't have to use this function, the idea which I want to solve is to use ajax to send my x,y coordinates of the joystick..

Comment: I don’t have time to make a detailed look, but just as a warning I don’t think this will work very well. The change event will get fired a lot faster than a network round trip.

Comment: I agree with Paul, using ajax will be too slow for input events like that. I'd recommend at the very least using a websocket so that the channel remains open instead of making a request per input.

Comment: If you really have to use ajax, don't send a request for every single change of the co-ordinates - it's long time since I've used a joystick but from what I recall you move it pretty fast. Even being a "virtual" one, I assume it could change position dozens of times a second, and soon overload your server with HTTP requests. Instead log the data client-side, and then send the latest set of data in a batch at timed intervals.

Comment: So guys you made a great point but... I'm using ajax to send data(coordinates) to my python controller in web2py application, which then uses socket to send it over wifi to micro controller. I can put delay between every sending of coordinates but the problem I cant make this sending of data constant. I can't even triger the function properly ..

Comment: probably you should add listener to the `keyup` event instead of the `change` event

Comment: if you want it "constant" (by which I take to mean streaming) then you'll probably want to use websockets. Ajax is a single one-time request, or, if called repeatedly, a series of separate individual requests, not suited to a constant flow of data. Also, "I can't even triger the function properly" means what? It never runs? It errors? Sends the wrong data? We can't see your HTML, so no idea if you've done this right at all.

Comment: I don't use keyboard here.

ADyson, yeah I can't triger this function, so basically it never runs

Comment: well do you have an element with `id="kk"` in your HTML? What type of element is it? Does it actually trigger "change" events (check the MDN docs)? BTW I'm on your question page right now but if you want me to get notifications at other times for your comments, tag me with an @ before my name.

Comment: @ADyson https://pastebin.com/8cumZ9zn here is the code, it's a total mess, and I'm a total beginner and a noob here so please have a understanding when opening this :) .. I didn't even edited to look nice, I just want to make it work for now. Ps. I added manual triger at the bottom of the code which of course doesn't work properly.

Comment: please paste the relevant parts into your actual question, not a 3rd-party site (links can change or die over time, making the question useless in future). Thanks. (https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic explains this)

Comment: Anyway it looks like it would work in theory, certainly the manual trigger should work. Have you checked your browser's console for errors?

Comment: @ADyson Ok I'll do that later. It wont work because the change is not triggered when you move the joystick. Input filled value is change when you change it and outfocus it, but with joystick moving you cant outfocus the input area

Comment: well that sounds like something to do with the joystick library. It's not clear whether it's even meant to update those fields or not. And just setting the value in the field via Javascript does not, of itself, trigger a change event. Perhaps you need to listen for some other event directly on the joystick library. I don't know, because I don't know the library or what its code does.